# Changing tmpdir in my.cnf causes mysql to fail to restart

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm trying to change where mysql uses for temporary tables.  I have a drive mounted at `/media/E`, and I've created a directory owned by `root` with permissions `drwxrwxrwxt` at `/media/E/tmp`.

I have changed `tmpdir` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to point to this directory.

I then restart mysql like so:

```
username@grey:/media/E/tmp$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Yielding the following error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here is the result of `systemctl status mysql.service`:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-08-05 16:56:07 BST; 3min 11s ago
  Process: 28964 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 28938 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24216 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 05 16:56:07 computer systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 05 16:56:07 computer systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 05 16:56:07 computer systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 05 16:56:07 computer systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 05 16:56:07 computer systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 05 16:56:07 computer systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

mysql error.log:

```
2021-08-05T15:56:05.385461Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-08-05T15:56:05.387065Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 28785 ...
2021-08-05T15:56:05.391963Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-08-05T15:56:05.391993Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-08-05T15:56:05.391999Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392009Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392014Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392223Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392308Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/media/E/tmp/ib0OZZH0' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392355Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392362Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392368Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392372Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392376Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392380Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-08-05T15:56:05.392398Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392455Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2021-08-05T15:56:05.392742Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2021-08-05T15:56:05.922766Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-08-05T15:56:05.924030Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 28830 ...
2021-08-05T15:56:05.927684Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-08-05T15:56:05.927705Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-08-05T15:56:05.927711Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-08-05T15:56:05.927716Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-08-05T15:56:05.927720Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-08-05T15:56:05.927725Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-08-05T15:56:05.927922Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-08-05T15:56:05.928009Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/media/E/tmp/ibTpGlkH' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2021-08-05T15:56:05.928121Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2021-08-05T15:56:05.928128Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2021-08-05T15:56:05.928133Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-08-05T15:56:05.928136Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-08-05T15:56:05.928140Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2021-08-05T15:56:05.928143Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-08-05T15:56:05.928160Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-08-05T15:56:05.928199Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2021-08-05T15:56:05.928422Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2021-08-05T15:56:06.432240Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-08-05T15:56:06.433500Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 28876 ...
2021-08-05T15:56:06.437655Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-08-05T15:56:06.437707Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-08-05T15:56:06.437716Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-08-05T15:56:06.437724Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-08-05T15:56:06.437732Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-08-05T15:56:06.437740Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438087Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438218Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/media/E/tmp/ibuYEQaa' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438274Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438285Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438293Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438299Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438306Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438311Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-08-05T15:56:06.438338Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438394Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2021-08-05T15:56:06.438799Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2021-08-05T15:56:06.933005Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-08-05T15:56:06.934428Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 28919 ...
2021-08-05T15:56:06.938763Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-08-05T15:56:06.938803Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-08-05T15:56:06.938812Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-08-05T15:56:06.938820Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-08-05T15:56:06.938828Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-08-05T15:56:06.938836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939095Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939192Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/media/E/tmp/ibrNdqJK' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939294Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939305Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939311Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939317Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939323Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939328Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-08-05T15:56:06.939373Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939481Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2021-08-05T15:56:06.939965Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2021-08-05T15:56:07.433078Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-08-05T15:56:07.434360Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.35-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 28966 ...
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438280Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438321Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438326Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438331Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438335Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438340Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438590Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438678Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/media/E/tmp/ibr3ovUd' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438726Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438733Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438738Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438742Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438747Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438750Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2021-08-05T15:56:07.438773Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-08-05T15:56:07.438824Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2021-08-05T15:56:07.439214Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: can you share full MySQL log so can I check .
make sure tmp dir have MySQL user ownership

Comment: Added the log file.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is armored by AppArmor, which does not allow writing freely to /media/E/tmp. To remedy the situation, you can edit the /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/user-tmp and add the /media/E/tmp there appropriately; for me the extra lines

```
  owner /media/E/tmp/**    rwkl,
  /media/E/tmp/           rw,
```

Comment: I added the line you recommended.  Same problem.  Do I have to perform any kind of restart on apparmor?

Comment: Also you can follow this blog 
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-apparmor-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: I restarted apparmor, and then restarted mysql and it failed in the same way.

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-apparmor-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux/

Comment: I followed the instructions on your link to completely disable apparmor.  It had no apparent effect on the problem.